como puedo resolver este error? The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Cuando ejecuto mi programa me aparece un error de que maven no ha encontrado The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available, volvi a crear la dependencia de Snapshot y aun no me lo agarra, este es el codigo que aparece en pom.xm, es mas que nada cuando me voy a la seccion de libros la cual esta conectada a una base de datos en mysql workbench y aparece este error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>BV</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.bv.BV</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project ```


Elimina la dependencia
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

de tu pom.xml, parece un placeholder que se ha generado pero sólo está evitando que tu código compile
